# TypeError: Cannot read property 'createHash' of undefined

Tags: ionic-framework, mini-css-extract-plugin

This is an error regarding ionic, I have just upgraded from IONIC 4 to IONIC 5. I have also upgraded my nodejs to latest version 12.16.4. Now I am getting error while performing ionic serve on my ionic projects. Could you please help me out in this regard?